# How to reuse a javascript function between content script and service worker in MV2/MV3-compatible way?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, es6-modules, firefox-addon-sdk, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In Chrome extension, I have a javascript function that I need to reuse both from content script and from background worker JS files.

How can I organize scripts for that?

---

So far I only managed to define reusable function in `common.js` as

```
export function commonFunction()
{
  ...
}
```

...and import it from `background.js`:

```
import { commonFunction } from './common.js';
```

However, I can not find a way to reuse that function *from content script*. Ideally I need the same code to be reusable between Manifest V2- and V3-browsers.

---

Also, stable Firefox (which is still MV2) fails with that design even for `background.js`: `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

The error message is not helpful as the `import` line *do* appear at the top level of a `background.js` module.

---

---

**Update 2:** This is the shortest solution I could make for Chrome MV3. Still need help to make it more simple / elegant:

```
async function commonImporter()
{
    return await import((chrome.runtime.getURL ||
      chrome.extension.getURL)("common.js"));
}

async function contentScriptFunctionUsingCommon()
{
    ...
    result = await (await commonImporter()).commonFunction();
    return result;
}
```

---

**Update 3:** For Firefox with MV2, I am strugging to create `background.html` properly: with pre-existing background.js, it reads now:

```
<script src="common.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="background.js" type="module"></script>
```

...while both common.js and background.js are also listed in `background.scripts` of `manifest.json`. However when I remove `scripts` array from `background` object of `manifest.json`...

```
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": false
    },
```

...Firefox gives error that I fail to google:

> Protocol error (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED): Component returned failure code: 0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED) [nsIInputStream.available] from: server0.conn0.webExtensionDescriptor304 (resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:777:0)

Answer (score 1):

For content scripts, the content script is not a module, but you can dynamically import modules. You can import a module like this:

```
import((chrome.runtime.getURL || chrome.extension.getURL)('...'));
```

Note that you will need to add any module imported this way to your `web_accessible_resources`.

For Firefox, the key part of the message is "of a module". Specifying background scripts directly (without a background page) does not make them run as a module. To get around this, add a background page and run your background script via a script tag with a type of `module`: `<script src="..." type="module"></script>`
For browsers supporting MV3, you would add `"type":"module"` to your `background` object instead.

Comment: Sorry, I grabbed the line from an MV2 extension originally. `chrome.extension.getURL` has changed to `chrome.runtime.getURL` for MV3. I updated it in the answer above.

Comment: Refer to the documentation for the dynamic `import()` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Comment: In particular, note that it *returns a promise* that will need to be awaited.

Comment: Posted my result as Update2. Still doesn't look very elegant to me, please help to simplify it.

Comment: I also failed to properly implement the background page for MV2 Firefox, see Update #3.

Answer (score 0):

For **MV3** (according to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code, **"Bundle third-party libraries"**):

```
    // manifest.json:

    content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
    "js": ["js/common.js", "js/process.js"]
    }

    // service worker (in this example is located in './js' folder):
    importScripts('./common.js')
```

It works fine for me without using modules.