# Failing to export to background.js from a common script under Firefox with MV3

Tags: javascript, import, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to [reuse some function between service worker (background.js) and content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421706/how-to-reuse-a-javascript-function-between-content-script-and-service-worker-in).

In Firefox with Manifest V3 (104.0b9 Developer Edition) I'm consistently getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

... while it works fine under Chrome with MV3 (104.0.5112.79).

I tried most variations found in https://javascript.info/import-export, but to no success.

Here is my sample code. For each experiment, I keep only one `import` line in `background.js`. However error message is always the same.

---

background.js:

```
import {commonApartFunction} from './common_apart.js';
import * from './common.js';
import { commonFunction } from './common.js';
import * as commonObject from './common.js';
import defaultFunction from './default.js';

function commonCaller() {
  commonApartFunction();
  commonFunction();
  defaultFunction();
  commonObject.commonFunction();
}
```

---

common.js:

```
export function commonFunction() {
    return 1;
}
```

---

common_apart.js:

```
function commonApartFunction() {
    return 2;
}

export {commonApartFunction};
```

---

default.js:

```
export default function defaultFunction() {
    return 3;
}
```

---

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Import-Export expriment",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Import-Export expriment",
  "author": "Jane Doe",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*.example.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "jane@doe.com",
      "strict_min_version": "66.0"
    }
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "common.js", "common_apart.js", "default.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://*.example.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are some considerations:

- Chrome MV3 uses [Service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#man-sw) (not `background.scripts`)

```json
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js",
  "type": "module"
}
```

- Firefox MV3 supports `background.scripts` as non-persistent event pages
- Background `"type": "module"` is not implemented in Firefox background Service Worker yet.

  - [Support type: "module" (background service worker as a ES
    module)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1775574)
  - [Support type: "module" (event page, not background service worker)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1811443)

You will get an error e.g.

> There was an error during the temporary add-on installation.
> Error details
> Extension is invalid
> Reading manifest: Error processing background: Value must either: contain the required "page" property, contain the required "scripts" property, or not contain an unexpected "type" property

- Latest Nightly (*106.0a1 at the time of posting*) supports MV3 Service Worker background by toggling these 2 in `about:config`, for testing purpose only, as API support is very limited at the moment.

  - `extensions.manifestV3.enabled`
  - `extensions.backgroundServiceWorker.enabled`

*Note: Updated based on information provided by mixedpuppy*

Comment: _MV3 uses Service worker (not "scripts")_: The [link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#man-sw) you referred to is Chrome-only. Firefox [still](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Background_scripts#specify_the_background_scripts) [expects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background#:~:text=Manifest%20version,2%20or%20higher) `background.scripts` in MV3.

Comment: Having `type: module` only adds warning _"Reading manifest: Warning processing background.type: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest"_ which doesn't affect anything. Removing `type:module` doesn't resolve the error _"Import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"_.

Comment: @wassrubleff Since Firefox support of MV3 is not complete yet, the MDN has not been updated yet. The MDN background document is for MV2, not MV3.

Comment: [As of July 4](https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext/issues/2379#issuecomment-1173745486), *"Firefox doesn't support service workers in extensions yet.... You can create two manifests, ... one with `background: { scripts: ['path.js'] }` for Firefox."*

Comment: @wassrubleff I have tested the latest Nightly, it requires a couple of `config` changes, but service worker works in Nightly but support is limited as mentioned the post. `background.scripts` belong to MV2 and not MV3.

Comment: That sound promising. Which config flags you changed to make it work?

Comment: @wassrubleff "type": "module" is not supported yet ... so it wont solve your problem. `extensions.manifestV3.enabled` and `extensions.backgroundServiceWorker.enabled`

Comment: Thank you for your time trying to help though!

Answer (score 2):

MV3 in Firefox supports background scripts as event pages and will continue to do so.  The MDN pages document the persistent flag differences in MV2 and MV3.  The extension workshop contains more information in the migration guide.  https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/manifest-v3-migration-guide/

Comment: Can you give more details? For the same `background.js` and exported scripts as in original question, import fails to work in MF3 environment with background page made of multiple `<script type="module" src="common.js"></script>`, one per JS involved, including `background.js`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a background page instead of the background script:

```
{
    "background": {
        "page": "background-page.html"
    }
}
```

And call your existing background script in the background page as a module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="module" src="./background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For manifest version v3,

If your background script file is `background.js` you should use below `manifest.json` format for Chrome and Firefox

For Chrome:

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
```

For Firefox:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "type": "module"
  },
```