# Have Typescript treat non-module scripts as isolated for browser extension development

Tags: typescript, browser-extension

The content scripts, background scripts and popup scripts used for web extensions are completely isolated from each other because they run on entirely different pages (with entirely different privilege levels).

But Typescript (and hence VSCode) assume that they run in the same global context. It thinks that functions are callable between different `.ts` files, and that functions with the same name are duplicate definitions.

`isolatedModules` is not a solution because would still incorrectly complain about duplicate function definitions.

`"moduleDetection": "force"` is not a solution because it explicitly adds empty `export`s at the end of the generate `.js` files, which means that the script is now interpreted by the browser as a module.

I am avoiding the module route because it is a minefield [littered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75452966) with [crappy workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121629). The whole infrastructure is screaming in my face that it doesn't want to be treated that way.

How do I make Typescript understand that the scripts are completely isolated from each other, while not having them be modules?